# Prevent heading from being located at the bottom of a page, but without setting it to always be at the top of a new page

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I am working on my thesis and I keep running into a very annoying issue.

The heading of a new section is located on the bottom of the page, and all the content of that section is located on the next page.

Is there a way to set Word to automatically move the heading (Whether it be heading level 1, 2, 3, 4 etc) to the next page, but ONLY when it is at the bottom of a page? I do *not* want the headings to always start on a new page.

My lab mates tell me this is easily done on LaTeX; however, nobody knows of a way to do it on Word.

Comment: Well, you can do this manually with page breaks. I'm not aware of an automatic way though.

Comment: I realize it's doable manually, but when you are dealing with this issue many many times, it becomes a little annoying (Especially when you have to make an edit and it throws everything out of whack)

Comment: Have you set "keep with next" in the paragraph settings for the heading style? If you have, make sure that the para. immediately following the heading isn't just a blank line. That should at least ensure that the heading isn't the very last thing on the page. But I don't think you can do much better than that in Word.

Comment: I agree with bibadia, how would you actually define "near the bottom of the page" in any case?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is the solution, as suggested in the comments:

1. Under the home tab, right-click the heading
2. Click modify
3. Under the Format drop-down list, click "Paragraph..."
4. Check the checkbox "Keep with next"

If the heading is at the bottom of the page, it will now move to the next page